# MySQL Left Join (Unknown Column)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am having problems with my query.

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`users`.`username`), `users`.`full_name`, `users`.`profile_picture_url`, 
`users`.`followed_by_count`, `users`.`follows_count`, `users`.`bio`, `users`.`id`
FROM `users`,`interests`
LEFT JOIN `blocked` 
ON `blocked`.`receiver_id` = `users`.`id`
AND `blocked`.`actor_id` = 100 
AND `blocked`.`blocked_reason` = 'Blocked'
WHERE `blocked`.`receiver_id` IS NULL 
AND `users`.`instagram_active` = 1 
AND `users`.`banned` = 0 
AND `interests`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
AND `interests`.`interest` = 'Food'
AND `interests`.`active` = 1 
AND `users`.`active` = 1
ORDER BY `users`.`last_login` DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

The error I am getting is this:

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'users.id' in 'on clause'

How is it an unknown column when I am SELECTing it?

I am very confused...

Users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (    
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `instagram_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `bio` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `website` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `profile_picture_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `full_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `media_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `followed_by_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `follows_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `last_updated_instagram` datetime NOT NULL,
 `instagram_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
 `inserted_on` datetime NOT NULL,
 `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `banned_reason` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `oauth_token` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `shown_to_others` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `credits_offered` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `registered_ip` varchar(17) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `credits` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `email_notifications` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `todays_followers` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `todays_followers_hour` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `total_followers` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `credits_yesterday` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `email_is_verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `email_announcements` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `email_credits` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `verification_code` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `country_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `browser_info_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `featured_user` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `emailed_credits` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `instagram_id` (`instagram_id`),
 KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
 KEY `browser_info_id` (`browser_info_id`),
 KEY `username` (`username`,`instagram_active`,`banned`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`browser_info_id`) REFERENCES `browser_info` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1279 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Interests:

```
CREATE TABLE `interests` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `interest` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `inserted_dt` datetime NOT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `interest` (`interest`),
 CONSTRAINT `interests_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4161 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Blocked:

```
CREATE TABLE `blocked` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `actor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `receiver_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `blocked_reason` enum('Skipped','Blocked') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `inserted_dt` datetime NOT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `browser_info_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `actor_id` (`actor_id`,`receiver_id`),
 KEY `receiver_id` (`receiver_id`),
 KEY `browser_info_id` (`browser_info_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `blocked_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `blocked_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`receiver_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `blocked_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`browser_info_id`) REFERENCES `browser_info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5700 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Could you post your table structure?

Comment: Just a heads up, your `DISTINCT(\`users\`.\`username\`)` won't actually select just the distinct `username`s, it will apply distinct to all columns.

Comment: @Brad Ok, sorry about the assumption but usually when I see someone use the brackets around the first column its because they think it will only apply to that column.

Comment: @andrewsi I have added table structure.

Comment: You might find that using table aliases makes your SELECT more readable - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As documented under [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html):

> #### Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - Previously, the comma operator (`,`) and `JOIN` both had the same precedence, so the join expression `t1, t2 JOIN t3` was interpreted as `((t1, t2) JOIN t3)`. Now `JOIN` has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`. This change affects statements that use an `ON` clause, because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes interpretation of what those operands are.
>
>   Example:
>
>   ```
>   CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT, j1 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT, j2 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT, j3 INT);
>   INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t3 VALUES(1,1);
>   SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Previously, the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) was legal due to the implicit grouping of `t1,t2` as `(t1,t2)`. Now the `JOIN` takes precedence, so the operands for the `ON` clause are `t2` and `t3`. Because `t1.i1` is not a column in either of the operands, the result is an `Unknown column 't1.i1' in 'on clause'` error. To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the `ON` clause are `(t1,t2)` and `t3`:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Alternatively, avoid the use of the comma operator and use `JOIN` instead:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   This change also applies to statements that mix the comma operator with `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and `RIGHT JOIN`, all of which now have higher precedence than the comma operator.

Comment: I read it and switched my tables in the FROM statement and it worked.

Comment: Great answer!  I was banging my head against the wall because my query would not work.  I read this answer, added parentheses around the tables in the ON statement, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: how about paraphrase

Comment: most useful answer, should come at top in google results. Could have saved my 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Your from clause is not joining between the tables.  If you want the query to parse, try this:

```
from `users` cross join
     `interests` LEFT JOIN
     `blocked`
     on . . .
```

Or, better yet, phrase the joins correctly:

```
from `users` join
     `interests` 
     on `interests`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` LEFT JOIN
     `blocked`
     on . . .
```

My advice to you is:  Don't use the "," in a FROM statement.  It means CROSS JOIN, which is a very expensive operation if you miss the condition in the WHERE clause.  The comma is easily missed.  You can delete the comma, and the second table becomes an alias for the first -- a very different meaning.  Also, don't put join conditions in the WHERE clause.  This is what the ON clause is doing.

I am, however, surprised that MySQL generates an error in this case, presumably because you don't have an explicit join between the tables.

Comment: If I want to select from multiple tables, don't I have to use commas to separate tables in the FROM statement?

Comment: @Brad: No, the implicit join syntax (indicated by a comma) is a relic of old SQL standards and is being gradually removed altogether.  Explicit join syntax (indicated by the `JOIN` keyword) is strongly recommended: one can string multiple such joins together by repeating the `JOIN` keyword: `FROM a JOIN b ON ... JOIN c ON ...`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Doesn't MySQL process inner joins with join criteria identically to cross joins with the same criteria in a `WHERE` clause?  In which case, I'm not sure you're right when you say it's "*a very expensive operation*" (although I do agree it's easily missed!).

Comment: @eggyal . . . I phrased it badly.  If you miss the condition in the WHERE clause then it's very expensive.  The ON clause is required for a LEFT/RIGHT/INNER/FULL OUTER join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Again, that's not entirely true for MySQL.  "*In MySQL, `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, and `INNER JOIN` are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent.*"

Answer (score 0):

It is true what MySQL says, because the ID column is not known at the LEFT JOIN time (it's done before table USERS is joined). Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( `users`.`username` ),
               `users`.`full_name`,
               `users`.`profile_picture_url`,
               `users`.`followed_by_count`,
               `users`.`follows_count`,
               `users`.`bio`,
               `users`.`id`
FROM   `users`
       JOIN `interests`
         ON `interests`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
       LEFT JOIN `blocked`
              ON `blocked`.`receiver_id` = `users`.`id`
                 AND `blocked`.`actor_id` = 100
                 AND `blocked`.`blocked_reason` = 'Blocked'
WHERE  `blocked`.`receiver_id` IS NULL
       AND `users`.`instagram_active` = 1
       AND `users`.`banned` = 0
       AND `interests`.`interest` = 'Food'
       AND `interests`.`active` = 1
       AND `users`.`active` = 1
ORDER  BY `users`.`last_login` DESC
LIMIT  0, 25
```