# Selecting from 3 tables when a value may not exist in third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

APPS

```
|---------------------------|
| app_id  |     app_name    |
|    1    |     Some App    |   
|    2    | Some Other App  |
|    3    |   custom_image  |
```

USER_APPS

```
|----------------------------------------|
| user_app_id  |   app_id   |  user_id   |
|      1       |      1     |     1      |
|      2       |      2     |     1      |
|      3       |      3     |     1      |
```

CUSTOM_IMAGES

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| custom_image_id  |   app_id   |  user_id   |       image_url     |
|        1         |      3     |     1      | /img/image_name.jpg |
```

This is just a sample to illustrate my problem. I need to select the values from all three tables for a given user, but nothing I do produces what I need.

What I have right now is:

```
SELECT ua.app_id, ua.app_position, aa.app_name, ci.image_url, ci.custom_image_id
FROM (app_user_apps AS ua, app_apps AS aa)
JOIN app_custom_images AS ci ON (ua.user_id = ci.user_id)
WHERE ua.user_id = :user_id
AND aa.app_id = ua.app_id       
ORDER BY ua.app_position
```

But this does not tie the image URL in the cutom images table to the apps table.

Comment: You need to use a "left join" instead of "join" which defaults to "inner join"

Comment: Where is `ua.app_position` declare?

Comment: @TJ-, might as well write that as an answer.

Comment: Not only do you need a LEFT JOIN per @TJ-, you need to get rid of the implicit join ( This -> `FROM (app_user_apps AS ua, app_apps AS aa)` along with `aa.app_id = ua.app_id` and make it an explicit join using `JOIN ... ON ...`

Comment: TJ You were correct. I would vote it as an answer. Max the app_position is in the user_apps table. AgRizzo, I tried a JOIN ON and it did not work, this post explained the reason, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443343/mysql-left-join-unknown-column

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding of your question this is my code that I made.

Code:

```
select app_id,app_position,app_name,image_url,custom_image_id
from app_apps aa
join user_apps ua on aa.app_id = ua.app_id
join app_custome_images ci on ua.userid = ci.user_id
where ua.user_id = ci.user_id and aa.app_id = ua.app_id
order by ua.app_position
```